# Draw path and create movable curves over MKMapSnapshotter image

Tags: ios, swiftui

The attached video is created with Swift code but I want this with SwiftUI.

I have created a map image with the help of MKMapSnapshotter and when I click on the draw path button it draws the path between 2 points with the help of Custom CALayer class. This creates the path and it can be moved with a finger and create a curve. After that I can preview the path which shows the curves with progress and I can export that as a video.

I am not sure how to do this thing with SwiftUI. I have googled but I have not found anything related to this. I have also checked links over stack overflow but nothings helps.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PWxQVCnf80BZR7DhghP4_UCZtRZXlzgU/view?usp=share_link

I have watched videos and searched for links over stack overflow but not found what I want. I want same thing but with SwiftUI.

Below is the class which I have used for Swift which works correctly. I want to convert it to SwiftUI.

```swift
type class BallPathLayer: CALayer {
    var isPathOnly: Bool = false
    
    var startPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    var endPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var seedPoint: CGPoint = .zero {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var pointCount: Int = 50
    
    var radius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return min(frame.width, frame.height) / 50
        }
    }
    
    let pointColor = CGColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    let pathColor = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    let lineColor = CGColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    let ballColor = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    @NSManaged public var progress: CGFloat
    
    
    func renderLayer() -> BallPathLayer {
        let layer = BallPathLayer()
        
        let renderScale: CGFloat = 3.0
        
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x * renderScale, y: startPoint.y * renderScale)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPoint.x * renderScale, y: endPoint.y * renderScale)
        layer.seedPoint = CGPoint(x: seedPoint.x * renderScale, y: seedPoint.y * renderScale)
        
        layer.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width * renderScale, height: frame.height * renderScale)
        
        return layer
    }
    
    
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(progress) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
    }
    
    private func bq0(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return pow(t, 2) * pow(1 - t, 0)
    }
    
    private func bq1(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return pow(t, 1) * pow(1 - t, 1)
    }
    
    private func bq2(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return pow(t, 0) * pow(1 - t, 2)
    }
    
    
    func getPoint(t: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        
        if t >= 0 && t <= 1 {
            x = endPoint.x * bq0(t) + seedPoint.x * bq1(t) + startPoint.x * bq2(t)
            y = endPoint.y * bq0(t) + seedPoint.y * bq1(t) + startPoint.y * bq2(t)
        }
        
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    
    func getPoints(_ progress: CGFloat) -> [CGPoint] {
        var result = [CGPoint]()
        let step = CGFloat(progress) / CGFloat(pointCount - 1)
        for i in 0..<pointCount {
            result.append(getPoint(t: CGFloat(i) * step))
        }
        return result
    }
    
    
    func getStartPoint() -> CGPoint {
        return startPoint
    }
    
    func getEndPoint() -> CGPoint {
        return endPoint
    }
    
    func getLinePoint(_ progress: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: startPoint.x - (startPoint.x - endPoint.x) * progress,
                       y: startPoint.y - (startPoint.y - endPoint.y) * progress)
    }
    
    func getPointsArray(_ progress: CGFloat) -> [Float] {
        var result = [Float]()
        
        for item in getPoints(progress) {
            result.append(Float(item.x))
            result.append(Float(item.y))
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        super.draw(in: ctx)
        
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
                
        let points = getPoints(progress)
        
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.setLineWidth(radius * 2)
        ctx.move(to: getStartPoint())
        ctx.addLine(to: getLinePoint(progress))
        ctx.setStrokeColor(lineColor)
        ctx.strokePath()
        
        if seedPoint != .zero {
            ctx.setLineWidth(radius * 2)
            ctx.setStrokeColor(pathColor)
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.move(to: points[0])
            for i in 1..<points.count {
                ctx.addLine(to: points[i])
            }
            ctx.strokePath()
            
        } else {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.setLineWidth(radius * 2)
            ctx.move(to: getStartPoint())
            ctx.addLine(to: getLinePoint(progress))
            ctx.setStrokeColor(pathColor)
            ctx.strokePath()
        }
        
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.addArc(center: getStartPoint(), radius: radius * 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        ctx.setFillColor(pointColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
        
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.addArc(center: getEndPoint(), radius: radius * 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        ctx.setFillColor(pointColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
    
        if isPathOnly == false {
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.addArc(center: points[points.count - 1], radius: radius * 2.5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
            ctx.setFillColor(ballColor)
            ctx.fillPath()
            
        }
        
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```